# Is the Pinterest "Any image on this page" pin-it button, supposed to show a pin count?

Tags: pinterest

The code for pinning any image on a page is as below:

```
<a data-pin-config="above" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" /></a><script src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

src: http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button

The option for `data-pin-config` is available, implying that a pin count should show. Upon testing this I am unable to see a pin count even though I have copied and pasted the code exactly. The pin works correctly and the page/image is pinned correctly to a board.

If Pinterestrelies on the image URL for the pin then I can understand why the pin count would not be showing, as any image on that page could have been the pinned image.

Basically, I am wondering whether the "Any Image On Page" pin option should show a pin count?

Comment: I have the same issue, pinterest support says rtfm and this https://help.pinterest.com/entries/21101982

Comment: Sometimes it takes a while for Pin count to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Any Image On Page button is not intended to show a pin count, so the widget builder should not have shown data-pin-config for the Any Image On Page version. My fault, sorry, fixed!